# PHP Win32 Exhausted memory, for loop, if condition not being met

Tags: php, codeigniter, out-of-memory

We've been working on a PHP program and it exhausts the server memory half way through.

Memory appears to be being used up on the false side of an if but we don't know why. The following example shows what the code is like at the relevant point:

```
$memory = new MemoryUsageInformation(true);
$memory->setStart();

$a = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++){
   for ($y=1; $y<=50; $y++){
      for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++){
         if ($a == 1){
            echo 'Do I get here';
            //30 + multidimensional arrays defined here.
         }
         $memory->setMemoryUsage('loop: '.$i.'.'.$y.'.'.$m);
      }
   }
}

$memory->setEnd();
$memory->printMemoryUsageInformation();

Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 34.25 MB | Info: Initial Memory Usage
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 34.25 MB | Info: loop: 0.1.1
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 36.00 MB | Info: loop: 0.1.2
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 38.50 MB | Info: loop: 0.1.3
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 41.50 MB | Info: loop: 0.1.4
...
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 111.50 MB | Info: loop: 7.50.9
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 111.75 MB | Info: loop: 7.50.10
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 113.25 MB | Info: loop: 7.50.11
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 116.25 MB | Info: loop: 7.50.12
Time: 1412155564 | Memory Usage: 117.00 MB | Info: Memory Usage at the End
```

When we comment out the arrays being defined in the if statement the memory is not exhausted and the program runs.

We have also tried echoing out text within the if to see if the condition is satisfied but this text was not echoed.

We're a bit stumped at this, would anyone have ideas or suggestions as to where to look deeper?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you looping 4800 times? And by your code, `$a` is never `1` so you are never creating any arrays. If you are though, come on. That's over 130000 multi-dimensional arrays. Even if each only had a footprint of 1kb in memory, that's still 130mb of memory usage. Why do you *think* you're running out of memory?

Comment: This is a snippet of code to illustrate the issue rather than the actual code itself. We are required to run this many loops due to the calculations that are needed. In the actual code the if condition is met in certain situations but in this scenario it is not.

Comment: We can't find your problem if you're not giving us your actual code.